# Hibernate: Is it mandatory to have mappings defined in entity classes to use joins using Hibernate criteria api?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I've three entity class with no mapped relations whatsoever either with annotations or in xml.

```
FILE_ACC_DETAILS:[REF_NO, NAME, TYPE,........];
FILE_DETAILS: [REF_NO, BATCH_NO, FINCL_YEAR,........];
FILE_STATUS: [BATCH_NO, STATUS, HASH, SEQ_NUM,........];
```

I want to do this query using the criteria api of hibernate:

```
SELECT acc.REF_NUM,acc.NAME,detail.BATCH_NO, detail.FINCL_YEAR, status.STATUS
FROM FILE_ACC_DETAILS as acc 
INNER JOIN  FILE_DETAILS as detail ON acc.REF_NO=detail.REF_NO 
INNER JOIN FILE_STATUS as status ON detail.BATCH_NO=status.BATCH_NO
```

Please consider that the common columns name maybe different in actual scenario. If not complete answer, conceptual explanation and partial example would be appreciated. Pls ignore if any syntax error in here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not do the right thing, and introduce an association between the entities?

Comment: It's an old application in which this search functionality needs to be added. So its not possible to change any pre existing thing.